# Encrypted file download

Tags: c#, arrays

What I need to do is consume a document from an API, but this document comes encrypted and for me to be able to download it I need to decrypt it and store it in a local string. The idea is that you don't need to use a blob, just the temporary cached file. So my logic was as follows: Get the document via code (this returns me a binary) > Convert the binary into an array > Convert the array into a FileStream:

```
private static byte[] data;
                   
public static byte[] Download(List<Document> documents)       
{       
    Download download = new Download();         
     
    foreach (Document document in documents)           
    {                       
        if (document.file_ != null)             
        {               `            
            using (var client = new RestClient(uri))                
            {                   
                try                     
                {  
                    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(document.file_, Method.Get);  
        
                    request.Timeout = -1;                                  
                    request.AddHeader("Content-Type_", "application/json");                                       
                    var body = @"{" + "\n" +
                        @"    ""justices"": [" + "\n" +
                        @"        { ""number"": ""24303016000131"" } " + "\n" +
                        @"    ] " + "\n" +
                        @"}";                   
        
                    request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);          `
        
                    RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);                                       
                    var ret = response.Content;                                     
                    data = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ret);               
                    download.binary = data; 
                }  
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;   //System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path. (Parameter 'path')'`
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return download.binary;
}
```

Here is my model:

```
public class Download
{
    public byte[] binary { get; set; }
}
```

I used this method to convert the array to File. Exception:  Message =Illegal characters in path. (Parameter 'path')

```
public static bool ByteArrayToFile(string fileName, byte[] byteArray)
{ 
    try 
    { 
        using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        { 
            fs.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); 
            return true; 
        } 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", ex); 
    } 
   
    return false;
}
```

I also tried decrypting what is returned to me from the API with the following method.

> Exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.

```
public static void Decrypt(byte[] downloadDoc)  
{  
    if (downloadDoc == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(downloadDoc)); 
    else if (downloadDoc.Length == 0) 
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(downloadDoc));
           
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    
    formatter.Serialize(ms, downloadDoc);
    var rt = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
      
    using (var rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        rijndaelManaged.KeySize = (rt.Length / 8) * 2;
        rijndaelManaged.Key = downloadDoc;
        rijndaelManaged.BlockSize = (rt.Length / 8) * 2;        

        using (var decryptor = rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor())
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            var decrypted = new byte[downloadDoc.Length];
            var bytesRead = cryptoStream.Read(decrypted, 0, downloadDoc.Length);
    
            var ret = decrypted.Take(bytesRead).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not used the `RestClient` but seeing as you are expecting a byte stream as the response I would use `HttpClient` directly. Writing code to get a string response and then converting that response back into bytes is error prone and also a bit convoluted. See [HttpClient.GetStreamAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstreamasync?view=net-7.0). You can then use that to write directly to a file or try to decrypt.

Comment: *Side note* - you should not write `throw ex;` when rethrowing an Exception. Instead just write `throw;`. The difference is that `throw ex;` will reset the call stack of the exception which will make it difficult to debug the Exception down stream as it will now appear as if the Exception originated from within the `catch` block.